# How to retrieve a public user's timeline from Facebook using facebook4j without the need for the user to login

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter4j

I have been searching on how to retrieve a public user timeline from Facebook without any authentication or sign in. The easiest library I found is facebook4j but I can't figure out how to achieve my goal(don't understand the access token). 
I have achieved my my goal for Twitter using twitter4j and my code is as follow:

```
class TweetFetch extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void>{
        private String convertedSingerName;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> nameAdapter;
        String user;
        ProgressDialog loadDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //get a loading animation
            /*loadDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            loadDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            loadDialog.setCancelable(false);
            loadDialog.show();*/
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

            convertedSingerName = Normalizer.normalize(singerName, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
            convertedSingerName = convertedSingerName.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
            convertedSingerName = convertedSingerName.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            user = convertedSingerName;
            nameAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) tweetList.getAdapter();
            getTweetOAuthDetails();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

               try{


            Paging page = new Paging(1, 50);//page number, number per page
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page);
            Log.i("Status count ", statuses.size() + " Feeds");
            for (int i=0 ; i<statuses.size() ; i++){
                twitter4j.Status status = statuses.get(i);
                publishProgress(status.getText());
                Log.i("Tweet Count" + (i+1), status.getText() + "\n\n");
            }
        }catch (TwitterException te){
            te.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            nameAdapter.add(values[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //loadDialog.dismiss();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

        }
    }
```

Is there anyway that I can use the same approach using facebook4j for Facebook. If this is not achievable using facebook4j what is the simplest way.
Thanks.